# Gradle build failing on different productFlavors

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing an application with two flavors as follow:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free"
        versionName "1.0-free"
    }
    paid {
        applicationId "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid"
        versionName "1.0-paid"
    }
}
```

Now I have admob dependency for the free version and want to make the paid version completely ad-free, hence deciding on compiling the dependency only for free version. I tried doing this as follow:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(":showmessage")
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
freeCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'}
```

and when I try to call the gradle task `installPaidDebug` it gives me the following error:

> /home/hemal/Desktop/Udacity-android-nd/Build It Bigger/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/paid/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>   Error:(33, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processPaidDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

But when I simple add the following line:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`
the project is build seamlessly.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: In your manifest you include a reference to value from the package `play-services-ads`. so you have to include it or edit your android manifest.

Comment: @ShadyAtef Can you please elaborate? Maybe an example?

Comment: @Khanal Okay. Will look out for the response there.

Comment: do you use the same manifest file for both paid and free version ?

Comment: @shadyatef you sir solved my problem. I had'nt until now, but based on your comment, I did, and it's working now perfectly. On a side note, do I need to add all the application tag contents, or just the meta-data content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to move the meta data tag from the manifest in your src/main directory to the manifest in your src/free directory.

```
<!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. --> 
         <meta-data 
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Your free manifest will look something like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     package="com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger" > 


     <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run --> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 


     <application 
         android:allowBackup="true" 
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
         android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > 


         <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. --> 
         <meta-data 
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 


         <activity 
             android:name=".MainActivity" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" > 
             <intent-filter> 
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 


                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
             </intent-filter> 
         </activity> 
         <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. --> 
         <activity 
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" /> 
     </application> 


 </manifest>
```

Comment: Do I need to add other tags such as <activity> tags or service tags to the free apps manifest file?

Comment: Yeah it will be very similar to the manifest in  src/main, added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use split manifest files, but note that manifest files are merged while building.
You can check [merging rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) to know more

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem before. The solution is manifest merging. Remove the meta-tag from common AndroidManifest and create another manifest in your free module and add meta tag in this AndroidManifest.

The problem is while building the paid version, there is a meta tag as defined in the manifest( because it is a common manifest), and no dependency (as you have added the dependency only in the free version). So the paid version cannot recognize what this meta tag corresponds to.